# How rip audio files from CD again?

Tags: windows-media-player, ripping

I've ripped music files from my CD but they were in .wma format and cannot play on my Android phone. So that I need to re-rip them into .mp3 files.

But the ripped button is disabled in Windows Media Player and the status of the file reads `Ripped tolibrary`

How can I force a re-rip/rip again?

Comment: I guess you'll have to remove them from your library, else just use better programs such as EAC + Lame to rip and convert.

Comment: @Karan Yeah, I have removed them and rerip again. I prefer to use the WMP as it is already available in the OS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest conversion rather than ripping again. Audacity is lightweight and works wonders. If you **have** to use WMP, then just delete previous files from your library (highlight and press delete).

Comment: I just didn't think of `delete` ^^ Thank you!

Comment: Converting from one lossy format to another adds additional loss.  It is better to go back to the original and rerip.

Comment: I agree with @Zoredache; unless the original ripping format was WMA lossless, re-ripping is the best solution.

Comment: Yeah right, I prefer to rerip. Conversion may make the sound differed

Comment: @Guillermo I prefer to use the WMP as it is already available in the OS

Comment: In addition WMP (now 12), while it has lost most of its qualities, must have kept its high rank (formerly #1) in ripping quality. I always rip CDs in mp3 128Kbps (i.e. 64Kbps per channel for CDs, that are always stereo). This is (with excellent ripping modules as WMP's one) the same quality as the often recommended 320Kbps (which is for 5 channels, i.e. 64Kbps per channel again)

Answer (score 0):

## Renaming doesn't work

Yes, I thought of removing the folder containing the ripped CD. Instead, I renamed from 'Edvard Grieg' to 'Edvard Grieg - WMA', but it still said the CD was already ripped. Then I simply deleted, and it did work! :D