# How can I rip audio files again, when Windows Media Player displays failed rips as 'Ripped to library'?

Tags: windows-media-player

> [ [Source:](https://superuser.com/a/575106/269574) ] If you **have** to use WMP [Windows Media Player], then just delete previous files from your library (highlight and press delete).

WMP deceitfully  displays files as 'Ripped to the library', even if they failed to be ripped. I  notice no 'Delete' button or option in WMP. Please see this screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Can you share some screenshots? It is hard to provide an answer right now as there are many places in WMP where this can be done

Comment: He means press "delete" on your *keyboard*.

Comment: @InterLinked Done. Better?

Answer (score 9):

I found that the check boxes to the left of the track number (column #) in Windows Media Player (12 at least) controls what will be ripped and in fact controls whether the Rip CD button is greyed out or not. Ignore the Rip Status column that says "ripped in library".

Answer (score 1):

Here are some steps you can take:

1. Try deleting the playlist itself if you don't need it. If it shows up under Playlists, delete it there. Otherwise, on the right-hand side, delete "Unsaved Playlist"
2. Use  the "Delete" button on your keyboard, as Android Dev [commented](https://superuser.com/questions/1058759/to-rip-audio-files-from-cd-again-with-windows-media-player-how-do-you-delete-pr#comment1487034_1058759).
3. Open the run Command and type the following without quotes. This will reset Windows Media Player and hopefully clear any playlists that are stuck in there.

   ```
    "msdt.exe -id WindowsMediaPlayerConfigurationDiagnostic"
   ```
4. If none of the above work, you can also reset WMP following these instructions: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-pictures/how-to-reset-windows-media-player-to-default/60c1903d-7bde-465a-8361-2e522ed742f1

Don't do #s 3 or 4 if you have data in WMP you want to keep as it may wipe them. Note that if you just have other playlists those are easy to recreate. Wiping Windows Media Player doesn't delete any of the songs or content that it has access to.

**Response to LePressentiment:** Have you tried steps number 3 and 4 or are you not willing to reset WMP? And just to make sure, there are no playlists listed under the "Playlists" tab but you see an 'unnamed playlist' anyways?

Comment: Thanks. Sorry if I am being careless. 1. I cannot appear to delete the playlist on the right-hand side? I can confirm the lack of any saved playlists on my computer. But 2 appears to function: thanks agian!

Comment: Thanks. +1. Please allow me a few days to try your suggestions in your response.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the destination of Ripped files (in Organise-Options-Extract music, change the destination folder), the status of the files will be blank again.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED - After you rip your CD, the "Rip CD" goes gray and is unable to be selected. There are check boxes to the left of each track. Check them all, then the "Rip CD" option in the menu bar at the top is once again selectable. Click on it, and Rip away! I didn't have to try to outsmart it by calling anything "Disk 2" or anything. Another thing I didn't think to do when I ripped my entire CD collection was to change the quality of my MP3s to "best quality". The default in Windows Media Player is lowest quality for smallest file size. So, I'll be re-ripping everything. Sigh . . .

Answer (score -1):

Just found the solution to this.
Insert the CD (if you have to, change it so CD does not eject automatically)
I selected all the tracks that had "ripped to library"
Go to Rip Settings at the top of the screen
click top menu option RIP..Disk 2 etc.